# pcre can not support mutiple subgroups

Tags: c++, c, pcre

This is about pcre multiple subgroups, subject is :

```
const char* subject = "http://mail.google.com:443";
```

I wanna to find protocol&domain&port, and my regex like this, but **pcre_exec return 0**

```
const char* regex_str = "([^/]+)//([^:]+):(\\d+)";
```

but when modify like this , pcre_exec return 2:

```
const char* regex_str = "[^/]+//([^:]+):\\d+";
```

well, what's wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pcre.h>
#define VECTORSIZE 6
int main()
{
    const char* subject = "http://mail.google.com:443";
    const char* regex_str = "([^/]+)//([^:]+):(\\d+)";
    const char* error = NULL;
    int erroffset = 0;
    int ovector[VECTORSIZE];
    char match[50];
    int matchlen = 0;

    pcre* regex = pcre_compile(regex_str, PCRE_CASELESS, &error, &erroffset, NULL);
    if(regex == NULL)
    {
        printf("error=%s,offset=%d\n", error, erroffset);
        return -1;
    }

    int matches = pcre_exec(regex, NULL, subject, strlen(subject), 0, 0, ovector, VECTORSIZE);
    printf("matches=%d\n", matches);
    if(matches == -1)
    {
        printf("no matches\n");
        return -1;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<matches; i++)
    {
        memset(match, 0, sizeof(match));
        matchlen = ovector[2*i + 1] - ovector[2*i];
        printf("start=%d, lenth=%d\n", ovector[2*i], matchlen);
        memcpy(match, subject + ovector[2*i], matchlen);
        printf("match=%s\n", match);
    }
    pcre_free(regex);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "can not support mutiple subgroups" - have you tried to verify this with a really simple regex? don't jump to wild conclusions.

Comment: my sample is simple enough

Comment: well, look at this:
    const char* server = "mail.google.com";
    const char* regex_str = "(\\w+).(\\w+).";

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
#define VECTORSIZE 6
```

Change it to 30 or something (ints are cheap) and it will work. pcre_exec needs 3 elements per subgroup and 3 more for the whole match. So in your example it needs to be at least 12.